# it's about fifty times?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> One evening, when Charlie went in to see his grand-parents, he said to them, "Is it really true that Wonka's chocolate factory is the biggest in the world?" "True?" cried all four of them at once. "Of course it's true! good heavens, didn't you know that? It's about fifty times as big as any other!"

In this sentence, what does "it's about fifty times as big as any other!" mean? 
Can someone explain it more easily? Is there another meaning of fifty without 50?

Comment: Measure the size of another chocolate factory.  Multiply that number by 50.  That's the size of Wonka's factory.  What don't you understand about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your passage it means Wonka's factory is the size of 50 of any other factory put together.

> It is 10 times the size of the Empire State Building.
>   It is ten times the size of the Empire State Building.
>   *it is the size of 10 Empire State Buildings put together*

There is no difference using numerals or writing out the number.